# Populating child object from Map in Java using Apache BeanUtils

Tags: java, apache-commons-beanutils

I am using `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate()` to poulate a Java bean from HashMap.

The java bean has a child object which is not populated. For eg. assume my Map contains a key "xyz" and in Java bean, the child object has the property "xyz" which i want to be populated from the Map but not getting populated.

Need some help.

Comment: Please add the code You are trying to do. If map is not populated then what are the errors you are getting.

Comment: not getting any errors..the value is set to null

Comment: still show us the code, even if there are no errors

Comment: Are you sure there is one (and only one) public method named `setXyz()`?  Can you post that method?  What happens when you call `setProperty(object,"xyz",value)` directly?